# Comparing each row of database values to my own values

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm a little confused by something that I hope you guys can help me solve, and this is the best analogy I could draw so that it makes a little more sense: say a database stores all the users' predictions of a basketball game, so the columns could be something like

```
id, user, homeTeamScore, visitingTeamScore, pointTotal
```

How could I see first if they predicted the `homeTeamScore` AND the `visitingTeamScore` exactly correct, and if not that, if they predicted the winner correctly (i.e see if their homeTeamScore - awayTeamScore > 0 in the case of a victory for the home team). Also, how could I increment pointTotal (based on the first case, I'd increment it by more than based on the second case since it's a more accurate prediction).

I'm sorry if I'm not being clear; if that's the case let me know and I'll try to restate it. Obviously because of the nature of my question, I'm not looking for very specific-to-my-problem answers; some SQL queries/PHP code structure for comparing database values would help an awful lot. Thanks again.

EDIT: I really wish I could select both your answers, or at least upvote them both but alas I don't have a 15 reputation. It worked exactly as I wanted though, so I thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You would use CASE or IF.

In the examples, I assume the home team scored 98 and the visiting team scored 95.  You get 10 points for being correct, otherwise 5.

CASE syntax:

```
UPDATE predictions SET pointTotal = CASE WHEN homeTeamScore = 98 AND visitingTeamScore = 95 THEN 10 ELSE 5 END
```

IF syntax:

```
UPDATE predictions SET pointTotal = IF(homeTeamScore = 98 AND visitingTeamScore = 95, 10, 5)
```

You can also (a) nest the conditionals and (b) use expressions instead of hard-coding point numbers.  For example:

```
UPDATE predictions SET pointTotal = 
  IF(homeTeamScore = 98 AND visitingTeamScore = 95, 
    10, 
    IF(homeTeamScore > visitingTeamScore, 
      GREATEST(1, 5-ABS((homeTeamScore - visitingTeamScore)-(98-95)), 
      0
    )
  )
```

In the example, you get 10 points for being perfectly correct, get 0 points for predicting that the visiting team will win, and from 1 to 5 for predicting that the home team won (the exact score is calculated based on your spread prediction versus the real spread).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

  CREATE TABLE my_table
  (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  ,user VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
  ,home_score INT NOT NULL
  ,away_score INT NOT NULL
  );

  INSERT INTO my_table (user,home_score,away_score) VALUES
  ('Alice',104,87),
  ('Ben',86,107),
  ('Charlie',92,111),
  ('Dave',96,98),
  ('Ellen',110,95);
```

Let's say the Croydon Fliers get beaten on their home turf by the Ealing Eagles, 92 to 111...

```
  SELECT *
       , CASE WHEN (home_score,away_score)  = (92,111) THEN 3 
              WHEN home_score < away_score THEN 2 
              ELSE 0 
              END points 
    FROM my_table;
  +----+---------+------------+------------+--------+
  | id | user    | home_score | away_score | points |
  +----+---------+------------+------------+--------+
  |  1 | Alice   |        104 |         87 |      0 |
  |  2 | Ben     |         86 |        107 |      2 |
  |  3 | Charlie |         92 |        111 |      3 |
  |  4 | Dave    |         96 |         98 |      2 |
  |  5 | Ellen   |        110 |         95 |      0 |
  +----+---------+------------+------------+--------+
```